# Extend JavaScript/JQuery accordion menu when JS is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo

**Question:** Is it possible to extend all accordion menus on page load if JS has been disabled?

**Background:** I have a client that wants to show/hide with a slide effect their "Sitemap" page but is worried about Search engines not getting to the links if they are hidden since from my understanding Bing and other bots ignore JS.

Comment: Design the site map so that it is visible without any JS. Make the JS collapse the site map once it loads.

Comment: Thank you for the great idea! I will recommend this to my client.